# WCF Service IIS to build user logged services for external clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

I'm starting in .net and wcf services, sorry if what i'm asking is wrong or has nosense. By the way, sorry for my english too.

I'm trying to build several WCF services hosted on IIS where the internet clients can login with their username / password (info stored in db). When they are logged, they can access their info, see their private documents, change their profile and more actions related to their account.

Well, in asp.net if I get the session after success login, i can build services like "GetMyDocs" and i know "who is", just checking the session username stored with the session ID when he calls the login and his session don't timed-out. But i've noticed that WCF Services are stateless, so this seems i have to send in all requests the username / pwd and check them in the DB before executing the service... always!?

Later, if i want to build a client desktop / Android / iOS application, i will use those services. They then can manage their personal and private data through those apps after a success login.

How should i handle this? 
Are WCF Services the way to go or WCF aren't a good choice for that? 
How can i handle the user identification with WCF? Because all my services are linked to a user and "GetMyDocs", "SaveNewConfig", "PayItem"... needs to identify who is calling.

Thanks in advance!! Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i've noticed that WCF Services are stateless

This statement is kind of wrong. Because you could easily create a "WCF-based" web service with state enabled. Furthermore, state is such a broad term that is not worth covering here. For example, you could use session state with a WCF service, or you could set the [`InstanceContextMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of a service to one of the following:

- PerCall
- PerSession
- Single

and of course, it all depends on how you configure the service itself.

If your service needs to be consumed by different clients, you should consider at implementing a RESTful service along with OAuth 2.0 or something similar where you can authenticate a request using the [Basic Authentication header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) or by issuing an [access token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_token) after a successful authentication.

Comment: But my WCF services will return different data related to the user. I thought RESTful services should be used when the data is the same for all users and not personal user. Sorry if i'm wrong.

I have read in many blogs / posts that WCF services works better with perCall and int most cases this shouldn't change. I'm a bit confused now :(

Comment: `I thought RESTful services should be used when the data is the same for all users and not personal user` this is a false statement

Comment: Seems i need to read more documentation :P thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to provide authentication to a WCF service.  One of them is by using a session (basicHttp does not support session, you have to use wshttp, or any of several other transports that support session).  However, enabling session is a huge amount of overhead simply to avoid sending credentials on each request.

Session reduces scalability by quite a bit, but if you aren't worried about it... it's an option.

Comment: But... checking those credentials querying my database everytime is a huge amount of overhead too, isn't it? And i've read that sessions in WCF don't work like ASP.net sessions storing data over requests.

Thanks for your reply but I'm sorry, still don't know how to handle my problem...